# A word that means "it only works if everyone does it".

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, fiat money or Facebook.  Fiat money only works because the whole community accepts it. Also, Facebook only has value because all your friends are on it.  I can't seem to think or find a word that embodies these properties.

Comment: A *social construct*, at a stretch?

Comment: I know lots of people who choose not to be on Facebook... That doesn't mean it has no value.

Comment: Herd immunity is used in the context of immunization, but that's a very specific and limited usage.

Comment: Perhaps.  I guess I was looking for something that can be applied in an economic sense as well.  For example, my examples would fail if everyone didn't agree to it.  I guess a social construct could work.

Comment: @Catija - I was speaking in much higher terms.  So, Facebook has over a billion people on there, if it suddenly drop to only 100 users then it would lose value.  Facebook is a platform for social interaction, if no one is a user of Facebook, then social interaction cannot take place, thus, the platform loses value.

Comment: Please provide an example of the context that you want to use the word for. Are you looking for a general word, something regarding technology solutions? Does your everyone need to be absolute?

Comment: Well, fairly obviously ***money*** is a "social construct". Even the use of gold to "back" paper currencies is little more than a convention. I was quite surprised to discover yesterday that one third of all the gold in the world is actually in India (hardly a particularly weathy nation when measured in dollar terms). And one third of all that *Indian* gold is actually held by [not-particularly-wealthy "housewives"](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/Households-hold-950bn-gold-in-India/articleshow/10987660.cms). Money is just whatever we *say* it is, not an absolute.

Comment: @Helmar - I was looking for something in general terms. General enough that it could be applied in multiple contexts.  Per Abhilaaj, an idiom could work too.  Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @user186530 please add those information to your original question, you can edit it to make it clearer and get better, more fitting answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using "Critical Mass".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_mass_(sociodynamics)

Answer (score 2):

I may suggest an idiom or two instead, just in case.
“it only works if everyone chips in”.

Or if everyone lends a helping hand.
[2]
Or "if everyone facilitates" may be.
Do let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Abhilaaj!   Your answers fit the question, so thanks for the answer!  I'm not sure those idioms fit my style though, but an idiom would definitely work!

Comment: Many many thanks. Do remain on line often. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Network Effect? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect).

It doesn't quite mean that *everyone* has to do the thing, but equally that is not the case in your examples of money and Facebook. It means that the value of the thing increases the more people do it. The classic example is a video phone, which does not work if you are the only person to have one, but gets more valuable the more people have them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **collaboration** suits here, e.g.

> Fiat money is a **collaborative** currency model involving the government and all citizens.

> Facebook's success is built on on billion users' **collaboration**.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaboration):

> **Collaboration** is the process of two or more people or organizations working together to realize mutual goals. Collaboration is very similar to, but more closely aligned than,cooperation, and both are an opposite ofcompetition.

Answer (score 0):

[Social consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theory) may be the driving force here.

> Consensus theory is a social theory that holds that a particular political or economic system is a fair system, and that social change should take place within the social institutions provided by it.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theory